# Service Reference (VS2013) more than one fault is declared with element name in namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, weblogic, visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to consume a web service created by Oracle Web Logic in Visual Studio 2013. I've added the service reference OK but when I call the service constructor I get the error:

> In operation (operationName), more than one fault is declared with element name (elementName) in namespace (namespace URL)

The snippets for this operation from the WSDL is shown in the image below:

[image]

This exception is thrown each time I attempt to use the service, and I can't proceed any further.

Is this an issue with the WSDL or is there something I can do as a consumer?

Comment: Do you by chance have the full wsdl available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the exact cause of the problem you are facing.
Can you try to generate the proxy using svcutil and give it the flag to generate using the xml serializer.

> svcutil.exe /target:code /dataContractOnly /serializer:XmlSerializer
>   /importXmlTypes  [your xsd file's path]

Here is a thread that talks about a similar problem with proxy generation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/66f8c5c0-0c3e-47de-abd3-ba6e1a228f2d/wcf-proxy-data-class-duplication-bug-generating-client-proxy-for-nonwcf-service?forum=wcf

Comment: one more link for your reference http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.com/2010/03/add-service-reference-duplicates.html

Comment: When you add a reference in visual studio thats pretty much what it does.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, your diagnostics allowed me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have some WSDLs that cause me grief in VS newer then 2008. I get around it by using VS2008 and adding the service references there. Then I can save and migrate the generated code over to my VS2010-13 projects. Unfortunately I have not yet found another solution.